# CENTOS, problems to identify why a user is using so much space

Tags: centos, disk-space-utilization

I am having disk space issues with my CentOS server, a single user is using up to 1,7tb of data, or it is what the du -sh* /home command is telling. But when you enter the user folder and use the du -hscx * command, it tells you that the user is  in fact using 480gb of space. I simply can't identify what is using the extra 1.3tb of space. Is there anyone here who knows how to deal with this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: `du -hscx *` does not look into hidden directories and files (starting with a `.`).

Comment: slm's answer here is useful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73818/how-to-find-free-disk-space-and-analyze-disk-usage